# How do I catch MongoDB's SocketException?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

With the [Java MongoDB Async Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/tree/master/driver-async) (I use an older version, 3.5.0 of it), when the connection breaks (purposefully shutting down the DB during testing) I get an `com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket` exception in a non-blocking thread/thread not owned by me. Specifically, the exception on the thread is `org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server <hostname>`.
I get no errors on any of my (visible?) threads, I don't have a blocking initialization thread.

How do I catch this exception and handle it?